# bullet point with different background images

Tags: html, css

Trying to make background images for instead of bullet points but can't see why they aren't displaying properly?

I need them to show a different background dependent on which bullet it is numerically. eg 10 bullets each with different backgrounds.

https://jsfiddle.net/bigdaddyt_351/nb21c7v4/1/

```
<ul>
    <li>bullet 1</li>
    <li>bullet 2</li>
    <li>bullet 3</li>
    <li>bullet 4</li>
    <li>bullet 5</li>
    <li>bullet 6</li>
    <li>bullet 7</li>
    <li>bullet 8</li>
    <li>bullet 9</li>
    <li>bullet 10</li>
</ul>


li{
    background: url('http://www.amiriconstruction.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Untitled-10.jpg') no-repeat left center;
    display:block;
    text-indent:15px;
    line-height:1.5em
}
```

Comment: Where's your differentiation? You have the same markup and CSS for each bullet.

Comment: not sure why you're marking me down. Im asking how to do it? I'm quite new to css and need help

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I can see why someone would. SO requires that you make an effort and show us what you've tried.

Comment: I did, https://jsfiddle.net/bigdaddyt_351/nb21c7v4/1/

Comment: There's nothing in that fiddle that attempts to differentiate by color. It's not an attempt to answer the question you've asked.

Comment: i used a sprite but couldnt figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to use the :before element and nth-of-type. eg

```
li:before{
    background: url('http://www.amiriconstruction.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Untitled-10.jpg') no-repeat left 50%;
    display:block;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    position:absolute;
    content: " ";
    top:10px;
    left:0;
}
li:first-of-type:before{
    background-position:0 0;
}
li:nth-of-type(2):before{
    background-position:-10px 0;
}
li:nth-of-type(3):before{
    background-position:-20px 0;
}
```

etc... https://jsfiddle.net/Luw0u4h2/2/

Answer (score 2):

The file is called as sprites. Each box is a single image in your case. In your CSS try this:

```
.bullet {background: url('http://www.tonytansley.co.uk/so/Untitled-10.jpg') no-repeat; display: inline-block; width: 12px; height: 12px; margin-right: 5px;}
.bullet-1 {background-position: 0px 0px;}
.bullet-2 {background-position: 5px 0px;}
```

And in your List Item, you need to remove the margin and padding. Use it this way:

```
li {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
```

And in the HTML give it as:

```
<li><i class="bullet bullet-1"></i> Hello</li>
```

And so on.

**Snippet**

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}

.bullet {background: url('http://www.tonytansley.co.uk/so/Untitled-10.jpg') no-repeat; display: inline-block; width: 10px; height: 10px; margin-right: 5px;}
.bullet-1 {background-position: 0px 0px;}
.bullet-2 {background-position: -10px 0px;}
.bullet-3 {background-position: -20px 0px;}
.bullet-4 {background-position: -30px 0px;}
.bullet-5 {background-position: -40px 0px;}
.bullet-6 {background-position: -50px 0px;}
.bullet-7 {background-position: -60px 0px;}
.bullet-8 {background-position: -70px 0px;}
.bullet-9 {background-position: -80px 0px;}
.bullet-10 {background-position: -90px 0px;}
```

```html
<ul class="bullets">
  <li><i class="bullet bullet-1"></i> Bullet 1</li>
  <li><i class="bullet bullet-2"></i> Bullet 2</li>
  <li><i class="bullet bullet-3"></i> Bullet 3</li>
  <li><i class="bullet bullet-4"></i> Bullet 4</li>
  <li><i class="bullet bullet-5"></i> Bullet 5</li>
  <li><i class="bullet bullet-6"></i> Bullet 6</li>
  <li><i class="bullet bullet-7"></i> Bullet 7</li>
  <li><i class="bullet bullet-8"></i> Bullet 8</li>
  <li><i class="bullet bullet-9"></i> Bullet 9</li>
  <li><i class="bullet bullet-10"></i> Bullet 10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @isherwood Where exactly is it?

Comment: I downvoted because 1) the OP is already using a sprite (as seen in the fiddle), and 2) because your solution requires a heap of one-off classes that simply aren't necessary. Much better to manage it in the CSS file than in the markup.

Comment: @isherwood I have corrected the wording. Even bootstrap, fontawesome and other similar stuff do the same. Do you agree?

Comment: Tried this first, it works well thankyou, the other answer had less code though so went with that

Comment: Bootstrap and FA use such classes where it's not practical to handle it in CSS, such as column sizing and single characters. I don't think you'll see examples like this, where an alternative exists outside the HTML markup. However, out of fairness I'll remove my downvote.